# android studio - Stuck in refreshing project build gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this very strange problem today with one of my projects and then creating a new project .

When I create a new project or open on of the projects , android studio open the project but then it stick on building gradle .All of my project has this line in build.gralde : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

all of the other project works fine and has no problem with gradle .

I replaced the .gradle folder from a working one but it didn't work .I restart my pc , invalidated it , restarted it .

At the end it says Gradle project sync failed or it stuck in refreshing gradle project and It couldn't create a new project ether .

What should I do ? I'm using android studio version 1.2.2 and the gradle version is 2.2.1 for all of the projects.

Comment: Which AS version you are used gradle udated https://gradle.org/getting-started-android/#developer

Comment: still the same ,I don't know what to do , Please help me

Comment: Most probably your connection is low and it is about 65MB, so it seems endless process as Android Studio not showing real progress percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Just be patient and go to C:\Users\USER_NAME.gradle\wrapper\dists\YOUR_CURRENT_GRADLE to see how it is downloading. On this file, press refresh to reload the content and see raw download speed.